# PHP exec with quotes

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to use the exec command from PHP in an XAMPP environment on Windows.

When I use a simple command line and type

"c:\Program Files (x86)\whatever directory\sometool.exe" "c:\temp\test.dat"

everything works perfectly.

Then I use exec command of PHP like so:

```
<?php
exec('"c:\Program Files (x86)\whatever directory\sometool.exe" c:\temp\test.dat');
?>
```

it also works. 
But when I include the quotes the tool seems to not get the parameter. That means

```
<?php
exec('"c:\Program Files (x86)\whatever directory\sometool.exe" "c:\temp\test.dat"');
?>
```

does not work. I have tried escaping and everything. I cannot find a solution. But I need quotes here in order to enable paths with spaces in the name. Can you point me into the right direction?

Comment: Are you using a very old (pre 5.3.0) PHP version?

Comment: Yes, it is actually 5.2.9 - is there a problem with pre 5.3 versions?

Answer (score 2):

Save your path as a variable.. then exec that. Wrap the path in single quotes like below.

```
$cmd = '"C:\my path with spaces\targetapp.exe" C:\mypathnospaces\targetfile.xxx';
```

OR - try this fix for spaces in everything, trying to use escape character on the backslash, this is  UNTESTED, let me know if it works or not.

```
$cmd = '"C:\my path with spaces\targetapp.exe" C:\\my other path with spaces\\targetfile.xxx';

exec($cmd)
```

Another solution would be to add the actual PATH to your windows environment, so that you do not need to call the path at all.

Comment: The path to the tool includig spaces is not a problem. The parameter including spaces is the problem.

Comment: @user1131536 - oh the second part "c:\temp\test.dat" with spaces? Hrmm.. I'm going to have to think about that, I think I have had that same issue once before. I'll edit my answer shortly I think I know what to do.